# i try to form a container which help me to display a text where the height of the container stretches to fit the text

Tags: html, css

i try to form a container which help me to display a text where the height of the container stretches to fit the text. i tried height: auto; but it still hide some of the texts when the text become longer.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with `height:auto`

Check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/YUTTh/